# Debian 10 Buster | update-grub | command not found

Tags: debian, grub

`update-grub` failed with an error message

```
# update-grub
bash: update-grub: command not found
```

@GAD3R Output of

```
# [ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo EFI || echo legacy
legacy
```

**Note1** I've installed Debian 10 Buster Alpha 3 release (Xfce) using the amd64 CD iso installer using a default installation (except that I removed the `print server` and added the `ssh server`).

**Note2** I used the root account (`su root`).

Comment: Welcome , please add the output of `[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo EFI || echo legacy`

Comment: Will `su - root` fix it?

Comment: Try with full path: `/usr/sbin/update-grub`

Comment: Thanks Rui, this worked. My expectation was that after a successful su, I should be able to call all binaries without extending the PATH.

Comment: Thanks Ipor, I've tried this one, and it worked, but following this way would lead me to modify all scripts I need to run.

Comment: Rui, please add your comment as an answer, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Solutions (best ones first)

1. `su - root` instead of `su root` - nicest solution (thanks to Rui)
2. extend path of the regular user in /etc/environment or ~/.bashrc or similar config file
3. call commands explicitly; using this solution would require that one modifies all scripts that happens to call another command from sbin (this is not practical, nevertheless there is an example of it in the troubleshooting section)

### Findings

This happened because the PATH works in a really strange way (actually works as designed).

1. `regular user login` -> environment PATH doesn't contain /usr/sbin => **opinion:** works as
   designed, quite logical
2. `su root` -> admin rights, but the environment is lacking /usr/sbin:/sbin
   => **opinion:** works as designed, but illogical, because **an account with root level of access should be able to execute commands from sbin without adding the path to the binaries manually**
3. `su - root` -> admin rights, /usr/sbin on the path => **opinion:** works as
   designed, quite logical

**Some more background**

There are two PATH defined in /etc/login.defs, but unless I start `su -` or `su - root`, I'm going to get the ENV_PATH.
I know that this has been designed this way, to keep the environment of the actual user, but in this single case, it really boggles my mind, why not add automatically `/usr/sbin` and `/sbin` to the path of a "regular user" after a successful `su root`

```
# cat /etc/login.defs |grep PATH=
ENV_SUPATH  PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
ENV_PATH    PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

---

### Troubleshooting

I've found that there is an `update-grub` command in `/usr/sbin`.

```
# find / -name update-grub
/usr/sbin/update-grub
```

Ran it, just to get the next error message.

```
# /usr/sbin/update-grub
/usr/sbin/update-grub: 4: exec: grub-mkconfig: not found
```

Searched for `grub-mkconfig` and found it under `/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig`.
Then it came to me, let's see how the `update-grub` script looks like?

```
#cat /usr/sbin/update-grub |grep grub-mkconfig
exec grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg "$@"
```

Modified /usr/sbin/update-grub in order to call `grub-mkconfig` by its explicit path ...

```
exec /usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg "$@"
```

... then called `update-grub` with its explicit path and tada, it worked!

```
# /usr/sbin/update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found background image: /usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-grub.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-2-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-2-amd64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.16.0-2-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.16.0-2-amd64
done
```

**Conclusion**

This must be something about the PATH.

Comment: Isn't it easier to run `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin` before running `update-grub` than editing these files?

Comment: @Moby04  A nice one! I'm going to check this soon.

Comment: Note that [according to Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/NewInBuster), previous versions of Debian used a version of `su` from the `shadow` source package, while Buster uses one from the `util-linux` sources, which won't auto-add the `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin` directories to `PATH` when switching to root. If you need to approximate the old behavior, you can set `ALWAYS_SET_PATH yes` in `/etc/login.defs`.

Comment: Nice finding and background @telcoM, much appreciated :) I still can't find a logical reason for such defaults ... grumble-mumble ... ;)

Answer (score 2):

This way:

```
#sudo update-grub
```

You need to run this command as root.

Comment: Needed even if root

Answer (score 1):

First update your local package list :

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Find correct boot mode :

```
[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo EFI || echo legacy
```

then, forced reinstallation of grub package for leagcy `grub-legacy` package is there and for efi `grub-efi` ( I'm assuming you boot mode is EFI ):

```
sudo apt install --reinstall grub-efi
sudo apt install grub-common
```

If still issue is not resolve, try this on :

```
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

`update-grub` command is just a script which runs the `grub-mkconfig` tool to generate a grub.cfg file. See the Archlinux GRUB [documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Generating_main_configuration_file)

**Ref :**

- [update-grub manage](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/grub-legacy/update-grub.8.en.html)
- [Debian grub wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Grub)

Comment: Boot mode is legacy.

Comment: Then use this command : sudo apt install --reinstall grub-legacy

Comment: Thanks Vipul, but this failed to resolve the issue too.

Comment: @linux64kb, try this one : sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg

Comment: Thanks Vipul, it seeems that the issue lies with the PATH, the grub itself is OK.

Answer (score -2):

You can force the reinstallation of `grub`:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall grub
```